How can i use MouseUp and RowColChange in VB6 to highlight a row in datagrid?
I am an novice to VB6.
I have an enhancement where there is a datagrid is pulling data from database. There are 2/3 rows. The requirement is to click on a row and to change the background and foreground for that role. Then i have additional button to reset that selection. There is additional code to trigger an SQL to get correct output.
I am using the below code snippets to execute
Private Sub DBGridRole_MouseUp(button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Dim selectedRowIndex As Integer
    Dim selectedColumnIndex As Integer
    
    If DBGridRole.Row >= 0 And DBGridRole.Col >= 0 Then
        'Get the index of the selected row and column
        selectedRowIndex = DBGridRole.Row
        selectedColumnIndex = DBGridRole.Col
        DBGridRole.BackColor = vbBlack
        DBGridRole.ForeColor = vbWhite
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DBGridRole_RowColChange(LastRow As Variant, ByVal LastCol As Integer)
    
    Dim selectedRowIndex As Integer
    Dim selectedColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    DBGridRole.Row = 0
    DBGridRole.Col = 0
    
    'DBGridRole.SetFocus
    'DBGridRole.Visible = True
    'DBGridRole.Refresh
    'Sleep 1000
    'DoEvents
    'MsgBox "Values are " + CStr(DBGridRole.Row) + " " + CStr(DBGridRole.Col), vbOKOnly
    
    If DBGridRole.Row >= 0 And DBGridRole.Col >= 0 Then
        'Get the index of the selected row and column
        selectedRowIndex = DBGridRole.Row
        selectedColumnIndex = DBGridRole.Col
        
        ' Set the DataGrid's Bookmark to the selected row
        With DBGridRole
        ' Remove previously saved bookmark from collection
            If .SelBookmarks.Count <> 0 Then .SelBookmarks.Remove 0
            ' Append your bookmark to the collection of selected rows
            If Not IsNull(.Bookmark) Then .SelBookmarks.Add .Bookmark
        End With
            
        For i = 0 To DBGridRole.Columns.Count - 1
            'Access the value of current Column in the selected row
            Sup_SelectedRole = DBGridRole.Columns(i).Value
        Next i
    End If
    
    If Len(Sup_SelectedRole) > 0 Then
        Selected_ReInit = True
        Call UserStatus_Click
    End If
    
    If Not Selected_ReInit Then
        Call MSFlexGridEmpl_Initialize
    End If
    ResetRoleView.Visible = True
    Selected_ReInit = False
    
    DBGridRole.Row = 0
    DBGridRole.Col = 0
    
    'DBGridRole.Refresh
    
End Sub


Now the problem i am facing is, the block is selected and then it again deselects.
I was using a message box to test it out. If the msgbox is there, then i am getting the result correctly.
As soon as that msgbox is removed then that block is not de-selected.
I checked online and found sleep function, doEvents, setFocus. I tried all of that and still not able to find a fix.
Would request a solution from VB6 experts.
